# How to append at the end of each \item?

Tags: enumerate, programming

I have an input file with a lot of items enclosed in `enumerate`. For an unknown reason, I have to append something (by calling a macro) at the end of each item.

I don't want to modify the existing input file by surrounding the contents of each item with a pair of curly braces as implemented in the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\message{This is the end of item.}

\let\olditem=\item
\def\item#1{\olditem#1\newline\message}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item {This is a book.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

## Questions

How to append a macro call at the end of each item but without having to surround each item contents with a pair of curly braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of `l3regex` we can get rid of blank lines preceding `\item` or `\end{enumerate}` and add `\mymessage` in the appropriate spots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,xparse,l3regex}

\let\latexenumerate\enumerate
\let\endlatexenumerate\endenumerate
\newcommand{\mymessage}{\mbox{}\\End of item}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewEnviron{enumerate}{%
  % remove all space tokens and \par preceding \item and prepend \mymessage
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\c{par}|\s)* \c{item} } { \c{mymessage} \c{item} } \BODY
  % remove the first \mymessage
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \c{mymessage} } { } \BODY
  % remove the trailing space tokens and \par and add \mymessage
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { (\c{par}|\s)* \Z } { \c{mymessage} } \BODY
  % do the standard enumerate
  \latexenumerate\BODY\endlatexenumerate
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

    \item This is a book.

    \item Other stuff 


    \item Well and here it goes again

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course the result would be the same for

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is a book.
    \item Other stuff 
    \item Well and here it goes again
\end{enumerate}
```

and I added the blank lines only by way of example.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way without packages.  One must be careful to avoid a blank line before `\item` invocations.  The MWE shows how it is set up to affect only `enuemerate` and not related environments like `itemize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\message{This is the end of item.}
\let\svitem\item
\let\svenumerate\enumerate
\let\svendenumerate\endenumerate%
\renewenvironment{enumerate}{%
  \def\newitem{\message\svitem}\svenumerate%
  \def\item{\let\item\newitem\svitem}%
}{
  \message\svendenumerate%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item B
\item[x] C
\item
\item D
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
\item x
\item y
\item z
\end{itemize}

\begin{enumerate}
\item P
\item Q
\item[x] R
\item
\item T
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not the best way, but it works for the first level of enumeration, however, not for empty `\item` commands.

I've prepended `\item` with `\newline` (Is it really necessary?) -- this does not work for the first item, of course and the last `\item` will not get it unless, `\endenumerate` is prepended to.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mymessage{This is the end of item.}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\item}{\ifnum\value{enumi} > 0  \newline\mymessage\fi}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\endenumerate}{\newline\mymessage}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is a book.
    \item Other stuff 
    \item Well and here it goes again
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And possibly avoiding to redefine the primitive `\message`. ;-) This won't work if there is a blank line before some `\item`

Comment: @egreg: Oh, yes of course ;-)

Comment: Does your implementation break `itemize`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Yes, unfortunately, but I think I can cure this