# Toggle between dotted lines/solution/blank space

Tags: macros, texstudio, exam, etoolbox

I want to learn how to create a command such that I can easily toggle between having dotted lines or solution or even blank space (no space) under my questions.

I know exam class has the `answer` argument that allows you to display your solution under the question but that only does half the job as it also displays the dotted lines above.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,answers,12pt]{exam}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question[1] $1+1$?
    \begin{choices} \choice 1\correctchoice 2\choice 3\choice 4\end{choices}
    \question[1]
    What is $1+1$?
    \fillwithdottedlines{2cm}
    \begin{solution}
        $2$
    \end{solution}
    \question Answer the following questions.
    \begin{parts}
        \part[1] What is $1-1$?
        \fillwithdottedlines{2cm}
            \begin{solution}
            $2$
            \end{solution}
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Ideally, I want to learn how to create a command that can easily toggle between these three states.
[image: Document with Lines]
[image: Document with no lines aka blank space]
[image: Document with solution displayed]

Comment: To clarify, the toggle can be applied "globally" (e.g. in the preamble)? Or do you want to be able to toggle each question individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach.

We define a new " if " `dotsolution`, using the [ifthen](https://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) package which `exam` already loads. Then, we store the old definition of `\solution` (what happens at `\begin{solution`), and add stuff to it. The stuff we add checks both `\ifdotsolution` and `\ifprintanswers`. If `\ifprintanswers` is true, we skip straight to the solution. If not, we check `\dotsolution`; if that is true, we print the dots, else we do nothing.

So, to toggle the 3 cases you can: a) use the `answers` option, b) don't use `answers` and set `\dotsolutionfalse`, or c) don't use `answers` and set `\dotsolutiontrue`.

Bonus: We add an argument to `\begin{solution}` for the height of `\fillwithdottedlines`. But of course, you can remove it and hardcode a value if you prefer.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{exam}

\newif\ifdotsolution
\dotsolutiontrue
\let\osolution\solution
\def\solution#1{%
  \ifprintanswers\else%
    \ifdotsolution%
      \fillwithdottedlines{#1}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \osolution%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question[1] $1+1$?
    \begin{choices}
      \choice 1
      \correctchoice 2
      \choice 3
      \choice 4
    \end{choices}
  \question[1] What is $1+1$?
    \begin{solution}{2cm}
      $2$
    \end{solution}
  \question Answer the following questions.
    \begin{parts}
      \part[1] What is $1-1$?
        \begin{solution}{2cm}
          $2$
        \end{solution}
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like the way you modified the``` \begin{solution}``` to add ```\begin{solution}{2cm}```. How would i go about modifying the ```\question[2]``` to ```\question[2]{3cm}``` so that it adds lines at the bottom of that question.

Comment: @AlanJones Can you clarify the purpose of the lines in that case? Based on the current problem, I figured they were space to write the solution. If we attach them to `\question`, then it will require a different approach.

Comment: See how you modified the the `solution` environment to include `{2cm}` at the end which adds the dotted line. I was wondering if we can also modify the `\question` command to include something like `\question[1]{2cm}` that will display the mark as well as the dotted lines at the end of the question. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: In effect rather than having to manually type `\fillwithdottedlines{2cm}` i can simply write `\question[2]{2cm}` which will display the mark as well as the dottedlines at the end.

Comment: I see. In the current solution, you don't need to type `\fillwithdottedlines{2cm}`, since it is part of the `solution` environment. But you want the behaviour without the environment?  Since the `\question` command is actually like an `\item`, I don't know if there is a hook to print material *after* the question text. You can consider one of the solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275253) that could help achieve this.